# Evaluating volume of cylinder shape by using spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I am trying to use spherical coordinates to find the volume of 1/2 of a cylinder with height = 1 and radius = 1.

[Area i wanna find is marked in blue spun around the z-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdjZF.png)

I wanna find a triple integral on the form:
$$ \int{\int{\int{\rho^2sin(\phi)\ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta}}} $$

The integral in terms of $\theta$ is from $0$ to $2\pi$

The integral in terms of $\phi$ is from $tan^{-1}(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

The integral in terms of $\rho$ is from $0$ to the line that goes from point C to y=1 which we can find using pytagoras:
$$ \rho = \sqrt{z^2 + r^2} $$
We know that $r$ always is 1 and $z = \rho cos(\phi)$ This gives us:
$$ \rho = \sqrt{\rho^2cos^2(\phi) + 1} $$
Solving this for $\rho$ gives us:
$$ \rho = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1-cos^2(\phi)}} $$

If we plug in the limits and solve the triple integral we get:
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}{\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-cos^2(\phi)}}}{\rho^2sin(\phi)\ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta}}} = \frac{2\pi}{3} $$

This volume will be 1/2 of a cylinder with height = 1 and radius = 1, the answer i expected was $ \frac{\pi}{2} $

I am not really sure where i am doing something wrong..

Comment: The integral you should be computing is $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\csc(\phi)}\rho^2\sin(\phi)d\rho d\phi d\theta$

Comment: @MatthewH. This still gives the same result as my attempt: $ \frac{2\pi}{3} $

Comment: You can check your answer by using shells to get the volume to equal $\int_{0}^{1}2\pi x\cdot xdx$ and get $2\pi/3$

Comment: The problem is that you don't have half a cylinder. You have a cylinder of radius $1$ and height $1$, from which you subtract a cone of radius $1$ and height $1$. So the volume will be $\pi r^2h-\frac 13\pi r^2 h=\frac 23\pi r^2h=\frac 23\pi$